# Got permission denied when writing to the second instance of Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My ionic app uses two firebase database instances. The rule allows everyone to read the data but requires the user to be authenticated in order to write to the database.

It works fine with the main database instance, but there is a problem with the second database instance: reading from it has no problem, BUT writing to the second database instance always error out with `Permission Denied` error.

If I change the rule to allow everyone to write, the second database instance will work as well. Here is what my rule looks like:

```
{
  "rules" : {
    "shuiyao" : {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth != null"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "database instance", do you mean shards within a single Firebase project, or two different databases in different Firebase projects?

Comment: It's one project with two databases.

Comment: It seems to me that each instance within the same project has separate rules.  Are you applying the same rules separately to each instance?

Comment: Yes, two separate rules. Since the data are different, the rules are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Based on the rules, both of these two database instances require user to authenticate in order to have write access. Since each database is configured/connected with only one single app, I ended up having 'two apps' in my application. After adding this new database instance, I should have changed my code to authenticate with the second app in addition to the default app if the user needs write access to both database instances.