# Firebase same user sign in anonymously on multiple sharded realtime databases

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

When using multiple Realtime Databases, Firebase forces you to authenticate each of the databases you want to use. I've seen this answered a few times [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935019/got-permission-denied-when-writing-to-the-second-instance-of-firebase-realtime-d) but don't see any examples of how to handle this for anonymously based sign-ins. Is there a way to take the anonymous authentication from the default Realtime Database and authenticate the same anonymous user on another Realtime Database (retaining the same user ID)?

As additional background, this is for an online game where users are matched to play against other users. One database should be used as a waiting room for the matchmaking whilst the other database would be for the game data itself. Load Perf is regularly meeting 100% as the matchmaking and game data are currently stored in the same database.

At the moment, I can anonymously authenticate a user on the different Realtime Database instances, but the user IDs are different. This is no good, as the user IDs need to be the same across both matchmaking and game data databases.

Comment: A user is authenticated to an entire Firebase project, not to specific a database instance within that project. It might help if you show the [minimal code, steps, rules and other information that is needed for any of us to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to find the problem and solution when going back to basics and finding an old Firebase blog post on the subject

Answer (score 1):

Having found an old article on the [firebase blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/11/easier-scaling-with-multi-database), I've found that the way to use multiple realtime databases without signing in to each one is different to the suggested approach for sharding in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances). The approach outlined in the Firebase Docs will mean that you need to authenticate each initializeApp instance separately, otherwise you will receive permission errors on all of the additional realtime database instances.

Instead of creating separate initializeApp calls, you should still just call it once and when using the non default databaseURL, provide this in the second argument of getDatabase eg getDatabase(firebaseApp, databaseURL). This will allow the same auth instance to be used for anonymous sign ins.

Comment: The Firebase auth instance and the Firebase Realtime Database instance/instance are not related. You can create any number of the Firebase Realtime Database instances even if you do not use authentication. However, in an app, you can have **only** one Firebase auth instance, while when using Firebase Realtime Database, you can create as many as you want.

Comment: This statement is **not** correct. "This will allow the same auth instance to be used." No, this will allow you to create multiple Firebase Realtime Database instances, regardless if you're using authentication or not.

Comment: Alex, you don't seem to understand that if you create multiple instances of initializeApp eg app1 & app2, you will need to sign in to both. This is a problem for anonymous sign ins as they become 2 different auth users. Try it for yourself before commenting & you will see. I appreciate your attempts to help but you simply don't understand the issue, which is probably my fault for a poor explanation. Here's [another post](https://daveteu.medium.com/multiple-firebase-realtime-database-permission-error-67db6c8d3f5c) which helped me to resolve the problem & explains the permissions error on app2

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to sign in anonymously to one Realtime Database and then auth the same anonymous user on another Realtime Database?

[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) is not related in any way to a [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). It's true that you can scale your data in Firebase Realtime Database by splitting your data across [multiple instances](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding), but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

> As additional background, this is for an online game where users are matched to play against other users. One database should be used as a waiting room for the matchmaking whilst the other database would be for the game data itself.

In such cases, you should create different nodes for different users. There is no need to create a new instance of the database in this case. Furthermore, Firebase Anonymous Authentication can easily solve your problem because it provides a unique ID for each user. So you can create a node for a user and another different node for the other user.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the issue I have is performance related in that  the load of my realtime database is regularly reaching 100%. This is why I need to split the databases up. The main perf hit is pinpointed down to the matchmaking process, so I figure that if this is put in a separate database this would mean performance of the game data isn't affected in any way.

As security rules are in place to lock game data down to just the 2 players, this is why user Ids need to be the same across both databases. There is also no sign up process so all users are anonymous

Comment: If you need multiple instances, then you can go ahead with that. But keep in mind that the ID of the user is the same with all types of authentication, including anonymous authentication. Besides that, it doesn't matter how many instances of the Realtime Database you create, the UID is always the same.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I have explained myself well. Each realtime database instance needs to be signed into anonymously but each time this is done a different UID is created. Is there a way to sign into 1 and then take that credential and sign into the other realtime database instance?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the relationship between Firebase Authentication and the Realtime Database. These products are not related. When you sign in, a new user is created in the Firebase Authentication, not in the Realtime Database. It's true, you can save user data in the Realtime Database by that's a different operation. You can assign for each user a new database instance but I think it will be easier to assign a node in a single database rather than creating multiple instances. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks, I understand the relationship. However, I'm strictly talking about an anonymous user that signs in and only has permission on the default realtime database instance. I need that same user to sign into the other realtime database using their same user ID. This doesn't happen automatically as you need to authenticate each realtime database separately as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935019/got-permission-denied-when-writing-to-the-second-instance-of-firebase-realtime-d). I understand it's easier with 1 instance but I need 2 working under the same auth.

Comment: Having two separate apps in a project is totally different than having two separate Realtime Database instances in the same app. Besides that, there is no concept of signing in, in the Realtime Database, you are only signing in, in the Firebase Authentication. Aside from that, this is what Firebase offers a single authentication that works with any number of Realtime Database instances. If you need different roles for your users then you have to define them in your application code and inside the security rules.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#connect_your_app_to_multiple_database_instances), Firebase tells you run initializeApp twice, meaning 2 separate app instances. Is this not the correct approach if I want to be authenticated with the same user on both realtime database instances?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You have to initialize both instances of the Realtime Database, but that has nothing to do with the Firebase Authentication. If you authenticate your user in Firebase, then you'll be able to access all instances of the Realtime Database you create. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks, that's good because it is what I'm currently doing. So which app, (app1 or app2) do I pass to the getAuth method in order to run signInAnonymously()?

Comment: None. You simply sign in anonymously and then you can create as many instances as you want. To create a new instance of the Realtime Database, you only have to pass the instance by URL, that's it. Nothing related to the authentication.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a permissions error on the 2nd realtime database instance when trying this as it isn't authenticated - which is what [this question explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935019/got-permission-denied-when-writing-to-the-second-instance-of-firebase-realtime-d). It seems that when you run getAuth without an argument it just authenticates the default app instance which would be the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex, I managed to find the solution and posted an answer detailing how I fixed it